# Simplifying an equality of products of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have five matrices $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, and I know that $ABC = DEC$. Can I conclude that $AB = DE$?

Comment: No. Trivial case: $C=0$. You can conclude that if and only if $C$ is right-invertible, that is $C$ is surjective.

Answer (score 4):

If $C$ is invertible, you can right multiply both sides of the equation by $C^{-1}$. One way to check if $C$ is invertible is to calculate if it has a nonzero determinant, assuming $C$ is a square matrix.

If $C$ is not square, this problem is more difficult, and you must check if there is a matrix $C'$ such that $CC' = I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.